Query_ball_point function for pointnet++
I am working on pointnet++ model of deep learning. I have completed my preprocessing steps and defining neural network and PointNet++ utility function. But there is one function caled as query_ball_point which is continuosly giving me errors.
The error is as shown below
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/models/pointnet2_utils.py", line 138, in query_ball_point
    group_idx[mask] = group_first[mask]
IndexError: The shape of the mask [8, 512, 3] at index 2 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [8, 512, 32] at index 2

This is the function for query_ball_point. I have done everything possible to solve this error and now I am unable to think of a good or correct solution
def query_ball_point(radius, nsample, xyz, new_xyz):
    """
    Group points within a specified radius around the new_xyz points.

    Args:
        radius (float): The radius within which to look for neighboring points.
        nsample (int): The maximum number of points to sample in each group.
        xyz (torch.Tensor): All points, shape (B, N, 3).
        new_xyz (torch.Tensor): Query points, shape (B, S, 3).

    Returns:
        torch.Tensor: Grouped point indices, shape (B, S, nsample).
    """
    B, N, _ = xyz.shape
    _, S, _ = new_xyz.shape
    group_idx = torch.arange(N, dtype=torch.long).to(xyz.device).view(1, 1, N).repeat(
        [B, S, 1])  # Initialize group indices

    sqrdists = square_distance(new_xyz, xyz)  # Calculate squared distances between new_xyz and xyz

    # Mask out points that are outside the radius
    group_idx[sqrdists > radius ** 2] = N

    # Sort indices based on distances and select the closest `nsample` points
    group_idx = group_idx.sort(dim=-1)[0][:, :, :nsample]

    # Handle cases where there are fewer than `nsample` valid points in the neighborhood
    group_first = group_idx[:, :, 0].view(B, S, 1).repeat([1, 1, nsample])
    mask = group_idx == N
    group_idx[mask] = group_first[mask]

    return group_idx

